# How to call parent component method from component/reactnode passed as props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am passing Button component as props of Toast component, so my custom button will be displayed inside toast component. If I click on button I need to call a method inside Toast component.

Toast usage:

```
const customActionButtonTemplate = ( 
<Mybutton label="Hide" onClick={// Here I wan t to call Toast components hideToast method//} />);

<Toast (...args)
customActionButtonTemplate = {customActionButtonTemplate()} />
```

Toast component:

```
export const Toast.FC<ToastInuts> = (props: ToastInputs ) => {
const hideToast(): void => {
   //toast clicked
}

return (
<div>
  <div>
    //contents
  </div>
  <div>
   {props.customActionButtonTemplate}
  </div>
</div>
)

};
```

Comment: You need to pass a ref to the Toast component with useRef(). In Toast, implement useImperativeHandle() and then you can call it from the parent. See the docs for more info on those two

Answer (score 0):

```
const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);

const customActionButtonTemplate = ( 
<Mybutton label="Hide" onClick={()=>hideToast(!hidden)} />);

<Toast (...args, hidden)
customActionButtonTemplate = {customActionButtonTemplate()} />
```

You extract state, setHidden function will be passed to button that you want, and you will just pass value of hidden to Toast, based on which you will hide or not hide the Toast

Comment: hideToast method is in Toast component, not in usage component. const customActionButtonTemplate = ( 
<Mybutton label="Hide" onClick={()=>hideToast(!hidden)} />); will throw error right?